# Instagram search API resulting no data for users

Tags: instagram

My python code fetches user details from the Instagram search API for the access token owner and also few other external accounts. Which worked fine until last week. Now the search API query results no data for the external users but for its own account its is resulting in data.

With instagram the access token doe not expire unlike facebook.
Have tried using new access token generated from a new account but results in no data.

search API- urllib2.urlopen('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/?access_token='+access_token)

Answer (score 1):

Check that you're not in sandbox mode, from 1 June 2016 all apps must require authorization from Instagram.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/